# How to execute three pythons scripts in parallel through bash file (Linux)?

Tags: python, linux, parallel-execution

I have three python scripts that I want to execute at the same time in parallel.
I use a bash file as follows:

```
python3 script1.py &
python3 script2.py &
python3 script3.py
wait
```

sometimes this works fine, other times it doesn't execute one of the scripts.
Can you tell me why?

By the way, I'm running this on linux terminal using the following command

```
sh filename.sh
```

Comment: try running `python3 script1.py &>/dev/null &`

Comment: what? I didn't understand your comment

Comment: How do you determine that one of the scripts is not being run?